# Video Capture with OpenCV on minimal Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to write a small test app with openCV, using Python, to capture frames from a Webcam.
My system is very minimal, and therefor I installed a minimal Ubuntu with Fluxbox.
I can't get any video capture happening with openCV.
When I try the same code on a more complete installation of Ubuntu (such as desktop, or Xubuntu and even Lubuntu) I am able to capture video easily.

My conclusion is that my minimal Ubuntu installation is missing something, and I am trying to find out what it is.

As for the details: I do see my camera listed with I run 'lsusb'
Also, when I execute:

```
cap = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
```

I do get a valid capture object. But when I try:

```
frame = cv.QueryFrame(cap)
```

I get a null object.

I installed python-opencv using apt-get rather than building it myself. It seems to work just fine on Xubuntu, Lubuntu etc.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme before, you must to have FFMEPG library installed on your computer for use this function
after you must do a cmake again and recompile opencv library

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python,u can install

```
pip install opencv-python
```

then you can use

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It works on any minimal setup.Thank you.